# Form submitting without refresh not working

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to submit a form without doing a hard refresh but my page is refreshing. I tried putting `action=“javascript:void(0);"` in the form tag but that didn't work. I also cannot use jquery.

Work Flow that causes error:

1. Submitting a form that is supposed to send some information to a php file.
2. Page gets directed to another page that doesn't exist.

   ```
       function toggle_visibility(id){
           var e = document.getElementById(id);

           if(e.style.visibility == 'hidden'){
               e.style.visibility = 'visible';
           }
           else{
               e.style.visibility = 'hidden';
           }

       }
       function createAjaxRequestObject() {
           var httpRequest;
           if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
               httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
               if (httpRequest.overrideMimeType) {
                   httpRequest.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
               }
           }
           else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
               try {
                   httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                   }
               catch (e) {
                   try {
                       httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                   }
                   catch (e) {}
               }
           }
           if (!httpRequest) {
               alert('Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance');
               return false;
           }
           // Create the object
           return httpRequest;
       }

       function sendTicket() {
           var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
           var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
           var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
           var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
           var msg = document.getElementById("msg").value;

           var encFirst = encodeURIComponent(firstName);
           var encLast  = encodeURIComponent(lastName);
           var encEmail = encodeURIComponent(email);
           var encsubject = encodeURIComponent(subject);
           var encmsg = encodeURIComponent(msg);

           var info = "firstName="+encFirst+"&lastName="+encLast+"&email="+encEmail+"&subject="+encsubject+"&msg="+encmsg;

           var http3 = createAjaxRequestObject();

           if (http3.readyState == 4) {
               if (http3.status == 200){
                   var result = JSON.parse(http3.responseText);
                   console.log(result);
               }
           }

           http3.open("POST", "send_mail.php", true);
           http3.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
           http3.send(info);

       }

   </script>
   ```

   ## Welcome!

   View My Tickets 
           Submit Ticket 
           Change my Password

   Full Name

   Email

   Subject

   Your Message *

Comment: Try putting onsubmit="return false" on the form instead of action="..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the `type` of you input from `submit` to `button` so the `sendTicket()` will be triggered, else the form will be submited before reached your `sendTicket()` function  so it should be :

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="sendTicket();" />
```

Instead of :

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="sendTicket();" />
```

Hope this helps.

```js
function sendTicket() {
  var firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
  var lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var subject = document.getElementById("subject").value;
  var msg = document.getElementById("msg").value;

  var encFirst = encodeURIComponent(firstName);
  var encLast  = encodeURIComponent(lastName);
  var encEmail = encodeURIComponent(email);
  var encsubject = encodeURIComponent(subject);
  var encmsg = encodeURIComponent(msg);

  var info = "firstName="+encFirst+"&lastName="+encLast+"&email="+encEmail+"&subject="+encsubject+"&msg="+encmsg;
  console.log(info);

}
```

```html
<h1>Welcome! </h1>
<div id="buttons">
  <button class="myButton" onclick="showTickets(); toggle_visibility('table');">View My Tickets</button> 
  <button class="myButton" onclick="toggle_visibility('Submit');">Submit Ticket</button> 
  <button class="myButton" onclick="toggle_visibility('changePassword');">Change my Password</button> 
</div>
<div id = "table"> </div>
<div id = "Submit">
  <form id = "emailForm" action="javascript:void(0);">
    <ul class="form-style-1">
      <li><label>Full Name <span class="required">*</span></label><input type="text" name="firstName" class="field-divided" placeholder="First" id="firstName" />&nbsp;<input type="text" name="field2" class="field-divided" placeholder="lastName" id = "lastName" /></li>
      <li>
        <label>Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="field-long" id= "email" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>Subject</label>
        <input type="text" name="subject" class="field-divided" placeholder="Subject" id="subject" />
      </li>
      <li>
        <label>Your Message <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <textarea name="msg" id="msg" class="field-long field-textarea"></textarea>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="sendTicket();" />
      </li>
    </ul>
  </form>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```